# How to obtain the value of an array exposed in var_dump from a SimpleXMLElement return?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, var-dump

I sorry for the aparently easy question for all you experienced developers. But I can´t obtain the answer in any place.  So I´ll try here. Maybe help other guy someday.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($object->ExecutarXMLResult->any);
var_dump($xml);
```

My var_dump is that:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) { ["listatomador"]=> array(104) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["id_pessoa"]=> string(4) "5251" ["nm_pessoa"]=> string(28) "Wilson" ["nr_cnpj_cpf"]=> string(14) "1" } } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["id_pessoa"]=> string(3) "939" ["nm_pessoa"]=> string(46) "Grupo" ["nr_cnpj_cpf"]=> string(14) "5" } }
```

So I you can see, I know there is 104 units of "listatomador" as explained in array(104). But how could I obtain it in my code? I tried every way and nothing.

Comment: Did you also try reading the [documentation for `children`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)?

Comment: I´ll try. Thanks. But I think may be a way to acesss this value directly. Or  Not. I really don´t know.

Comment: You have a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). The only ways in which you can interact with it are laid out in the documentation (since it's `Traversable`, you can also use `foreach`). It's not voodoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over each index ..

```
foreach ( $xml as $item ) {
       // ... 
}
```